# XAML in WP8.1: Child Element Styles

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, element, children

I have a `Grid` and `TextBlock`s. I want to style all `TextBlock`s within the `Grid`. So I do this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,15" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
        <TextBlock Text="myText" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" />
        <TextBlock Text="myText" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBlock Text="123456" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Foreground="{ThemeResource PhoneAccentBrush}" />
        <TextBlock Text="123456" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Foreground="{ThemeResource PhoneAccentBrush}" />
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

1) It's not working. `TextBlock`s don't get any `Margins`. Why?

2) How can I set the `Style` and `Foreground` properties of `TextBlock`s in the `<Grid.Resources>` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***1) It's not working. TextBlocks don't get any Margins. Why?***

It's not working because you're assigning the style "`TitleTextBlockStyle`" to the `TextBlocks`. So the implicit style you defined in `Grid.Resources` doesn't come in to play. Remove the  `Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"` parts from the `TextBlock`s, and your margins will appear.

***2) How can I set the Style and Foreground properties of `TextBlock`s in the `<Grid.Resources>` tag?***

The same as you set everything else:

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="AliceBlue"/>
```

or if you have a more elaborate brush:

```
    <Setter Property="Foreground">
       <Setter.Value>
        <!-- Whatever brush you want -->
       <Setter.Value/>
    </Setter>
```

I assume that with *"Set the style property of TextBlocks"*, you actually want your new style to inherit from an already defined style. In that case you can base your new style on an already existing style:

```
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource StyleToInheritFrom}">
```

or, in your case, presumably:

```
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,15" />
    </Style>
```

The full thing would look something like:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,15" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
        <TextBlock Text="myText" />
        <TextBlock Text="myText" />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBlock Text="123456" />
        <TextBlock Text="123456" />
    </StackPanel>

</Grid
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. For number (2), could you plz provide an example for Forground={ThemeResource PhoneAccentBrush} and Style={StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}?

Comment: I included an example for the whole XAML part.

Comment: Great! Thanks. And one more question. How can I change Forground color for only 2 TextBlocks in the second column? You can see my code to get what I want.

Comment: Then either 1) create an additional style, and give it a key (using the x:Key="..." syntax), or 2) exclude the Foreground from the style you just defined, and set it explicitly like you're doing now.

Comment: this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683(v=vs.110).aspx (Styles & Templating), and this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh758287.aspx (StaticResources) should set you on your way :)

Answer (score 0):

What sort of margins are you looking for? If you are looking for left right margins, its due to your margin declaration. Declare like this:

```
<object Margin="left,top,right,bottom"/>
- or -
<object Margin="left,top"/>
- or -
<object Margin="thicknessReference"/>
```

Right now, you're just adding a bottom margin. You could also just add

Margin="15"

which will be interpreted as a thickness reference and set all values to 15